# Can I delete the app.vue file from my Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt 3 and following some tutorials I have seen that they delete the ***app.vue*** file and create the ***pages/*** directory and inside it they put the index.vue file which would be the entry point of the application is this correct or should I leave the app.vue file as the entry point of the application?

I have tried removing the ***app.vue*** file and also leaving it and I have not noticed any difference.

Comment: That works without app.vue means that Nuxt has some default component when it's missing (it's the same in other frameworks), so you can remove it but it's more convenient to keep it in case you need to customize it in future.

Comment: can you give me an example when you say I can customize it later? what can I add, if you want to add something global you can do it in the layout or not?

Comment: There may be multiple layouts, it would be DRYer to put common code for global behaviour a level above, which is app comp. Here's an ex. from the docs, https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/features/layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can delete it out and even you can make a directory of layouts with default.vue in it and add the header and footer component there.
But if i were you i did not do that because if you want to add an

```
<NuxtLoadingIndicator :throttle="0" :height="2" class="bg-orange" />
```

for showing the progress bar in changing pages it is better if it in all pages with different layouts appeare
even if you want to use a toast for notification, in this case nuxt ui

```
<UNotifications />
```

it is better to comes in app.vue just like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLoadingIndicator  :throttle="0" :height="2" class="bg-orange" />
    <NuxtLayout>
      <!-- <SeoKit />
      <OgImageScreenshot />
      <OgImageStatic /> -->
      <NuxtPage/>
    </NuxtLayout>
    <UNotifications />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, now I understand it better.